# How to convert an analog signal to an impulse signal?

Tags: discrete-signals

I have several analog signals with constant amplitude in time. What I want is a way to convert these analog signals to an impulse signal i.e. a signal that consists of impulses occurring at different instants of time.

The conversion should be such that it should be possible to differentiate between different analog signals just by looking at the impulse signals that they have been converted into? Also the impulse signals should be of finite duration.

I don't come from a signal processing background so my question might not have a lot of info required.

Please let me know if there is any other info that's needed.

Thank you.

Comment: So your continuous signals are simply $x(t)=c$ for all $t$ with a given constant $c$? I don't understand what kind of information should be conveyed by the location of the impulses of the converted signal. Or do you mean to convert the number $c$ (i.e., the amplitude) to a binary format consisting of 1s and 0s?

Comment: All the analog signals don't have a constant amplitude. Lets say I have certain numbers between 0 & 1. There can be infinite numbers between 0 & 1. I need a way to convert these numbers to an impulse signal such that different numbers would have different impulse pattern.

Comment: From what you're saying I understand that you actually want to quantize analog signal values to binary bit streams. Of course you can only distinguish a finite number of values, otherwise your binary bit streams become infinitely long. Have you had a look at [pulse-code modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation)?

Comment: You mean there is no way I can work with finite number of bits if I have infinite analog values...

Comment: Well, a finite number of bits offers a finite number of different bit combinations, so you can only represent a finite number of different values. What you get is called quantization, i.e. an (arbitrarily small) interval of analog values is mapped to the same bit pattern.

Answer (score 0):

An approach for converting an analog signal into a bitstream is to use [delta-sigma modulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-sigma_modulation). Intuitively, the idea is to build a sequence of binary pulses such that, when it is low-pass filtered, you recover the input signal.

It is not clear what you mean by "differentiate". There are many conversion processes for which distinct inputs will yield distinct outputs. But I you suspect that you expect something like "similar-looking inputs should yield similar-looking outputs". The question is what kind of definition of "similar-looking" you have in mind...

Comment: I will use my example of infinite numbers between 0 & 1. Lets say that I have the numbers .01356, .01349 & .01692. I am trying to convert then to an impulse signal. The impulse signals should be such that they are different for all the three numbers but the signals for first 2 numbers are closer to each other than that of the third number.

Comment: I guess I should have asked this question along with 

http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9721/is-there-any-way-two-differentiate-between-impulses?noredirect=1#comment16529_9721

But now I can't combine them into one, still you can refer that question and it might answer your question.

Comment: "Closer to each other" according to each distance?

Comment: What if I answer you like this: represent the value 0.01356 as a 32-bit floating point in the IEEE 754 format. You get a sequence of 32 0s or 1s. To compare these sequences, interpret them as IEEE 754 32-bit floats and compute the distance.

Comment: Another solution: represent 0.01356 as a sequence of 1356 1s and 98644 zeros. To compare sequences, count the number of 1s.

Comment: These are a bit caricatural but I'm sure you have implicit requirements on the encoding or the distance function that you forgot to give...

Comment: I get your point but the thing is that numbers between 0 and 1 was just an example. The range of numbers is not fixed. And in case of numbers that don't have a fixed range it becomes difficult to decide on the number of bits I can start with. Moreover using so many bits would be a bad idea as the calculation of distance would become a time consuming process.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyways.. I know I haven't been able to present my question properly thats because of my limited knowledge about the field. Can you suggest some other techniques like delta-sigma modulation pointed by you above that I can read on and try to figure out if there's is anything that suits my needs.